# SQL Server - How to enforce a field value from a combination of fields not repeated with another field value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know I haven't framed the question very well, to be honest I found it difficult to explain without an example.

I have a table with SalesPersonID and SalesPersonSSN fields.

[image]

My requirement is a SalesPersonID should only exist with one SalesPersonSSN and vice versa.

If you see the table (sample data), the record with SalesPersonID 2003 is invalid because SalesPersonSSN 3344556677 already exists with SalesPersonID 2001. Similarly SalesPersonID 2001 should never exist with other than 3344556677. 
I don't know how to enforce this rule in the table. 
Also is there a simple query to find out if the rule is violated.

Comment: But a given ID could have multiple different SSNs? And a given SSN could have multiple different IDs? I smell a big problem.

Comment: Is it sufficient to ensure that every `SalesPersonID` is unique and every `SalesPersonSSN` is unique? Using a _unique constraint_ on each column will handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `unique` constraint :

```
alter table t
    add constraint ssn unique(SalesPersonSSN);
```

If you want the data that violates the rules you can use `exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 
              from table t1 
              where t1.SalesPersonSSN = t.SalesPersonSSN and 
                    t1.SalesPersonID <> t.SalesPersonID
             );
```

Comment: A unique constraint is also needed on `SalesPersonID` in order to guarantee "SalesPersonID should only exist with one SalesPersonSSN and vice versa." Otherwise a single person's inside diameter could be associated with multiple (unique) SSNs. Similarly, the query to identify _bad_ data needs to check for the alternative condition.

Answer (score 1):

To find out if your rule is violated you could use the follwowing

**Table**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (SalesPersonId INT, SalesPersonSSN VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2001,'3344556677'), (2002,'7755330099'), (2003,'3344556677')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    @t t
INNER JOIN (SELECT  SalesPersonSSN
            FROM    @t
            GROUP BY SalesPersonSSN
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
         ) a
 ON a.SalesPersonSSN = t.SalesPersonSSN
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the complete logic for it:

```
declare @ssn as varchar(255)='7755330099' --INPUT
declare @pid as int=201 --INPUT

declare @ssn1 as varchar(255)--local variable
declare @pid1 as int --local variable

select @pid1=SalesPersonId from #t where SalesPersonSSN=@ssn;
select @ssn1=SalesPersonSSN from #t where SalesPersonId=@pid;
if(@pid1 is not null and @pid1<>@pid)
begin
print('failed: as person '+cast(@pid1 as varchar(255))+' already asigned to ssn#'+@ssn)
end
if(@ssn1 is not null and @ssn1<>@ssn)
begin
print('failed: as ssn#'+@ssn1 +' already asigned to pid# '+cast(@pid as varchar(255)))
end
```

Table definition:

```
create TABLE #t(SalesPersonId INT, SalesPersonSSN VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (2001,'3344556677'), (2002,'7755330099'), (2003,'3344556677')
```